make : Nothing to be done for MakeFile
I have created a new requirenemts.txt file which contains
click
yaml
I have a makeFile in which i have added the below line
install: 
    pip install /app/src/requirements.txt

Now when i am running command :
make MakeFile

it says

make : Nothing to be done for MakeFile

What I am missing ?
I am on python version 3.12

Use make install to run that rule. make Makefile looks for a rule beginning with Makefile:

What does this have to do with Python?

As an aside, can I ask why you ran make Makefile?  My guess would be that you wanted to specify explicitly that make use the makefile named Makefile.  If that is the case then you probably wanted make -f Makefile.

Addition to @Barmar comment and a slight change
install:
    pip install -r requirements.txt

You should use
make install

